# Разные версии библиотек в CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Либа GeoFire требует либу Firebase версии 3.1.1, в то время как актуальная версия firebase - 4

Что делать в такой ситуации? Возможно ли как-то настроить поды так, чтоб GeoFire скачал старую версию firebase и внутри себя использовал ее?